# What is one way that I can reduce .includes association query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an extremely slow query that looks like this:

```
people = includes({ project: [{ best_analysis: :main_language }, :logo] }, :name, name_fact: :primary_language)
               .where(name_id: limit(limit).unclaimed_people(opts))
```

Look at the `includes` method call and notice that is loading huge number of associations. In the [RailsSpeed](https://www.railsspeed.com/) book, there is the following quote:

> “For example, consider this:
>
> ```
> Car.all.includes(:drivers, { parts: :vendors }, :log_messages)
> ```
>
> How many ActiveRecord objects might get instantiated here?
>
> The answer is:
>
> ```
> # Cars * ( avg # drivers/car + avg log messages/car + average parts/car * ( average parts/vendor) )
> ```
>
> Each eager load increases the number of instantiated objects, and in turn slows down the query. If these objects aren't used, you're potentially slowing down the query unnecessarily. Note how nested eager loads (parts and vendors in the example above) can really increase the number of objects instantiated.
>
> Be careful with nesting in your eager loads, and always test with production-like data to see if includes is really speeding up your overall performance.”

The book fails to mention what could be a good substitute for this though. So my question is what sort of technique could I substitute for `includes`?

Comment: Are you retrieving  all relation, you've included?

Comment: If you mean if whether I am using all the relations that I've included then yes. These models are needed for a view.

Answer (score 0):

*Before i jump to answer. I don't see you using any pagination or limit on a query, that may help quite a lot.*

Unfortunately, there aren't any, really. And if you use all of the objects in a view that's okay. There is a one possible substitute  to `includes`, though. It quite complex, but it still helpful sometimes: you join all needed tables, select only fields from them that you use, alias them and access them as a flat structure.

Something like

*(NOTE: it uses arel helpers. You need to `include ArelHelpers::ArelTable` in models where you use syntax like `NameFact[:id]`)*

```
relation.join(name_fact: :primary_language).select(
  NameFact[:id].as('name_fact_id')
  PrimaryLanguage[:language].as('primary_language')
)
```

I'm not sure it will work for your case, but that's the only alternative I know.

Answer (score 0):

```
I have an extremely slow query that looks like this
```

There are couple of potential causes:

1. Too many unnecessary objects fetched and created. From you comment, looks like that is not the case and you need all the data that is being fetched.
2. DB indexes not optimised. Check the time taken by query. `Explain` the generated query (check logs to get query or `.to_sql`) and make sure it is not doing table scan and other costly operations.

Comment: For #2, ActiveRecord has built-in [explain](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#running-explain)